# security in azure service bus relay

Tags: azure, azure-servicebusrelay

when working with service bus relay how's the security done?. Both transport and message level? If we use SAS key based sb endpoint does it mean it is https by default? At Message level I believe we have to do the regular encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

It uses either TCP, HTTP, or HTTPS depending on what you select. If you set it up so it uses client authorization, it will block you from using HTTP.